# How may I use double cross in HTML

Tags: html

What code I should put like the below image?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that just a combination of strikethrough and underline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strike through, and underline-

```
.line-through{
text-decoration:line-through;
}

.underline
{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer. Isn't there any way to do it without CSS? I want to do it with just HTML attributes

Comment: Use this- `<strike>strike</strike>` and for underline `<u>underline</u>`

Comment: `<strike>` and `<u>` tags that only indicate visual style and have no inherent semantic meaning. `<del>` and `<ins>` are more semantically valid. The CSS provided in this answer is also overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage indicates that you should use the `<del>` and `<ins>` tags. This actually gives your markup *meaning*, not just decoration.

```
I use <del>MAC</del> <ins>Microsoft</ins>!
```

It also happens that those tags add the styling that you want out of the box.

Sources:

- [`<del>` element - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/del)
- [`<ins>` element - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/ins)